# Error 403 while deploying function to firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

While deploying function for firebase storage, I'm getting error 403:

[image]

What might be possible reason? Any help would be appreciated.
Actually this is not my project, I'm working on collaboration with a team. Can it be a reason? Because if I try in my own project it succeeds.

Comment: What role do you have on the project? To be able to deploy functions you must at least be an editor iirc.

Comment: Yes i'm editor. I'm using service account private key like: const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({keyFilename: 'path/to/servicekey'});    
 Can this be reason??

Comment: Nope. That might affect invoking the functions, but not deploying it. The error message shows that you don't have permission to enable the required Cloud APIs. I'd triple check whether you are deploying to the correct project, because that seems the most likely cause.

Comment: okay, I got it, you are correct. Till now i was deploying to wrong project, actually both named nearly same. Thanks @Frank van Puffelen.

Comment: Good to hear that you found it Rishab. And also quite good that Firebase kept you from deploying functions to sombody else's project. :-)